# How to fix 'cannot find module' error for a barrel file?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting error

`Error TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module '@core/store/products'.`

when I have a barrel file in the folder `src/app/core/products` and use the following the import statement.

`import * as fromProducts from '@core/store/products';`

The `tsconfig.json` has the following configuration, and exists in the **app** folder of my angular file.

```
"paths": {
      "@core/*": [ "src/app/core/*" ]
}
```

If I use the file name directly, it works.

Comment: Hi wonderful world, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the src directory:

```
"paths": {
      "@core/*": [ "app/core/*" ]
}
```

Comment: That did not fix.